# Systematically rename complex character strings in R

Tags: r, rename

I have a data frame with ~20K column names formatted similarly:

```
data_colnames <- c("testosterone_f30850_0_0","testosterone_f30850_0_1","testosterone_f30850_0_2","apolipoprotein_a_f30630_0_0","apolipoprotein_b_f30640_2_0","cholesterol_f30690_0_0","hdl_cholesterol_f30760_0_0")
```

That is, the strings always end in '`f#_#_#`' where each '#' can be any number of digits in length

I need these columns to read:
"x30850_0_0", "x30850_0_1", "x30850_0_2", "x30630_0_0", "x30640_2_0", "x30690_0_0", "x30760_0_0"

In a text editor I can rather simply do a find replace for:
`any_word_characters_f#_#_#` with `x#_#_#`
but I am terrible at doing these substitutions in R.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will keep only an `f` followed by numbers and underscores at the end of each string:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(data_colnames, pattern = "f[0-9_]+$")
# [1] "f30850_0_0" "f30850_0_1" "f30850_0_2" "f30630_0_0" "f30640_2_0" "f30690_0_0" "f30760_0_0"
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. I'll just add the following code to convert the fs to xs: `colnames(data_colnames) <-
  str_replace(colnames(data_colnames), pattern = "f", replacement = "x")`